# Text based Data Entry

Tags: perl

I want a sample text-based data-entry template in Perl (console application) that can run through telnet. E.g:

```
 Name:___________________  Education:____________________
 College:__________________ Address:____________________
```

The user has to enter in the relevant fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can take input by reading from the special file handle `STDIN`. Loop through the fields you want inputted, and store the results in a hash:

```
my @fields = qw/name education college address/;
my %data;
for my $field ( @fields ) {
    print "$field: ";
    chomp( my $input = <STDIN> );
    $data{$field} = $input;
}
printf "Hello, %s!\n", $data{name};
```

`chomp` removes the trailing newlines.